# How to upload image to mongodb using node.js, express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Am trying to upload image to the task collection in my mongodb but keep getting an error message.

here is my task model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    completed: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    }, 
    avatar: {
        type: Buffer
    }
},
    {
    timestamps: true
})

const Tasks = mongoose.model('Tasks', taskSchema )


module.exports = Tasks
```

Here is my task router code

```
router.post('/tasks/me/avatar', auth, upload.single('avatar'), async (req, res) => {
    const buffer = await sharp(req.file.buffer).resize({ width: 250, height: 250 }).png().toBuffer()
    req.tasks.avatar = buffer
    await req.tasks.save()
    res.send()
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: error.message })
})
```

error message

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

It keeps giving me an error message of cannot set property 'avatar' of undefined, meanwhile the avatar field has already been defined in the task model.

How can I fix this issue, thanks.

Comment: Pleas check the error message image. It's not loading, i can't see it.

Comment: forget the image this is the error message "cannot set property 'avatar' of undefined"

Comment: Obviously, req.tasks does not exist. How do you call for req.tasks? Are you using mongoose for this?

Comment: yes I am using mongoose

Comment: Right, i got it. I'll send an answer.

Comment: I sent an answer. Check it out and tell me if that did it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok after looking at your answer i'll propose this solution.

Instead of:

```
req.tasks.avatar = buffer
await req.tasks.save()
```

Try this

```
 const query = {id: docId}; //prepare a query to find the doc
 Task.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: {avatar: buffer} }, ()=>{
   /Your callback function to run after completed
 });
 //Then call findOneAndUpdate method from any mongoose.model
 //Which will do exactly what its name says:
 //Finding ONE element, the first one matching your query
 //And then update any values inside $set
 //And after that you may use any callback function
```

Let me know if that helps you out.